# Give user access to URL based on condition (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url

This is in continuation to the stakoverflow question below

[Set different hyperlink for same <a> tag (Using AngularJs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412717/set-different-hyperlink-for-same-a-tag-using-angularjs/36412926#36412926)

I have 2 URLs as shown below. Pre.html and Block.html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a ng-model="data" ng-href="{{ data ? 'Pre.html' : 'Block.html' }}" target="_blank">Pre or Bloc</a></li> 
</ul>
```

This basically checks the value of data in the controller and loads Pre.html if $scope.data is true. It loads Block.html if $scope.data is false.

So, with this i am able to achieve the following

1) User clicks on link. User is shown block page if value of 'data' is false at the controller

2) User clicks on link. User is shown pre.html page if value of 'data' is true at the controller.

But when user type the link in URL, he is still able to access the Pre.html even when the $scope.data is set as false.

How can i block this URL access when $scope.data is set as false. > any suggestions

Comment: You will need to add logic in the route's controller to either prevent the user from seeing the page or reroute them if the data and the page don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not be achievable since when the user types in the URL himself; your $scope changes and is no longer accessible.

One way around this is to set the value in the $window variable instead; this can be pinged from the controller you defined for Pre.html.

For example:

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('PageCtrl', [ '$scope', '$window', $location, function($scope, $window, $location) {
    if (some condition) {
        $window.sessionStorage.data = true
    } else {
        $window.sessionStorage.data = false
    }
}
```

If the condition is false, just redirect the user back to the previous page or a default homepage.

```
controllers.controller('PreCtrl', [ '$scope', '$window', $location, function($scope, $window, $location) {
    if ($window.sessionStorage.data) {
        // Do something?
    } else {
        $location.path('#/home');
    }
}
```